# Style for image which is displayed in variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display one image( myimage1.jpg) and have an option where you can click on it and appears another image(myimage2.jpg ).

The clicking part works fine, now my question is how I can apply some style to second image(myimage2.jpg).

The whole idea is to make gallery where clicking on each image it enlarges and has small description.

Very beginner in code ;)

that's what I've got

js

```
 <script> var onImg= "myimage1.jpg"; var offImg= "myimage2.jpg"; </script>
```

html

```
<img src="myimage1.jpg" onclick="this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImg : offImg);"/>
```

Comment: p.s. All the suggestions are more than welcome

Comment: on the onclick= add a class / or take one away

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript for it.

After you have fired the image changing code, use javascript to modify the style of the img tag.

For example:

```
document.getElementById("id-of-image").style.height = "100px";
```

Comment: only one of the images(myimage1.jpg) has id. The second image is not displayed in html or css, it appears only by click.

Comment: So I couldn't figure out how to style var offImg= "myimage2.jpg";

Comment: Yes, but the id of the image will not change when the src is changed.
`<script> var onImg= "myimage1.jpg"; var offImg= "myimage2.jpg";  document.getElementById("id-of-image").style.height = "100px";
</script>`

Comment: Thanks men for your response but still , I could not figure it out :D, could you drop me some alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

how should the gallery look like?
If you are just looking for a Lightbox or Slideshow, than I would recommend to use a plugin for that. Many of them are free to use and they are developed by some people, who are not beginners. (Keep also attention to what browsers you want to support, because some libraries just work in modern browsers)
There are hundreds of these plugins out there.
Just google for "slidehow" or "lightbox" :)

But if you will build this little feature alone, than I would know, how the gallery should look like.
I've created two little gallery example for you, on the fly.

- [Expand Image Example](http://tinyurl.com/oxn79p6)
- [CSS Gallery Example](http://tinyurl.com/q6m4slj)

Has one of them a similar behaviour?

It would also be nice, if you could make a jsfiddle too. :)